# DeeplabV3 MobileNetV2 Quantization for USB Coral TPU with custom input size ((100, 100) rather than (513, 513))

Tags: python, tensorflow, quantization, google-coral, deeplab

I have been following the steps in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/394baa9f21424d3522ccfbdcee8acd3840891ff6/research/deeplab/g3doc/quantize.md to quantize a DeeplabV3 MobileNetV2 model for the USB Coral TPU but I cannot get it to work.

Even when I start from the models provided at the bottom (not the 8_bits, the raw models), I cannot get it to run. And I even get different problem for both models.

For the deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_train_aug:
- The `deeplab/train.py` script for quantizing runs successfully.
- The `deeplab/export_model.py` scripts step works.
- The `tflite_convert` works too.
- EdgeTPU compiler gets cryptic error message: `Internal compiler error. Aborting!`

For the deeplabv3_mnv2_dm05_pascal_trainaug:
- The `deeplab/train.py` script for quantizing runs gets:
`ValueError: Total size of new array must be unchanged for MobilenetV2/Conv/weights lh_shape: [(3, 3, 3, 16)], rh_shape: [(3, 3, 3, 32)]`
I tried [this solution](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7869) unsuccessfully.

- Using the .pb file directly, the `deeplab/train.py` with quantization aware training fails with python crashing.
- Doing a post-quantization in python directly works.
- edgetpu_compiler works.
- But once ran on the TPU, we get 0.87 TPS, most likely because the edgetpu-converter cannot convert all to edgtpu.

Any guidance to get it working would be great. I am also open to solutions not following the guide from tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've reached out to us and my colleague already shared the procedure, but I'll sahre it here for other to reference:

```
python deeplab/export_model.py \
    --checkpoint_path=../../deeplabv3_mnv2_dm05_pascal_trainaug_8bit/model.ckpt \
    --quantize_delay_step=0 \
    --crop_size=55 \
    --crop_size=55 \
    --model_variant="mobilenet_v2" \
    --decoder_output_stride="" \
    --export_path=../../deeplabv3_mnv2_dm05_pascal_trainaug_8bit/frozen_inference_graph.pb \
    --depth_multiplier=0.5
```

```
tflite_convert \
  --graph_def_file=../../frozen_inference_graph.pb \
  --output_file=../../frozen_inference_graph.tflite \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --input_shape=1,55,55,3 \
  --input_arrays="MobilenetV2/MobilenetV2/input" \
  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --std_dev_values=128 \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --change_concat_input_ranges=true \
  --output_arrays="ArgMax"
```

Answer (score 0):

change value in deeplab/common.py

```
flags.DEFINE_float('depth_multiplier', 1,...
```

to

```
flags.DEFINE_float('depth_multiplier', 0.5,...
```